# Buggy merge sort implementation

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

My merge sort implementation is buggy since i am not getting two sorted list before calling merge.I am not sure what is wrong with it.

```
def mergeSort(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1 : return arr
    mid = len(arr) // 2
    left_half = arr[:mid]
    right_half = arr[mid:]
    mergeSort(left_half)
    mergeSort(right_half)
    return merge(left_half,right_half)

def merge(list1,list2):
  res = []
  i = 0
  j = 0
  while i < len(list1) and j < len(list2):
    if list1[i] < list2[j]:
      res.append(list1[i])
      i += 1
    elif list1[i] > list2[j]:
      res.append(list2[j])
      j += 1
  #Add remaining to res if any
  while i < len(list1):
    res.append(list1[i])
    i += 1
  while j < len(list2):
    res.append(list2[j])
    j += 1
  return res

A = [5,1,2,15]
print(mergeSort(A))
```

My understanding of merge sort is that the space complexity is O(n) since n items in memory (in the final merge).Is quick sort preferred over merge sort just because quick sort is in-place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 mistakes in your code.

The first is that you don't handle the empty list. You need a `<=` instead of an `==` in your second line.

The second is that by simply calling `mergeSort(left_half)` you suppose that it will sort `left_half` “by reference”, which it doesn't (same with `right_half`).

The third is that you aren't doing anything in the case `list1[i] == list2[j]`. Actually you don't need that `elif`, you simply need an `else`. It doesn't matter whether you append `list1[i]` or `list2[j]` if they are equal, but you must append one of the two.

Your code should rather be:

```
def mergeSort(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1 : return arr
    mid = len(arr) // 2
    left_half  = mergeSort(arr[:mid])
    right_half = mergeSort(arr[mid:])
    return merge(left_half, right_half)

def merge(list1, list2):
    res = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(list1) and j < len(list2):
        if list1[i] < list2[j]:
            res.append(list1[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            res.append(list2[j])
            j += 1
    #Add remaining to res if any
    ...
```

As for your questions about space complexity and comparison with quicksort, there are already answers here on StackOverflow ([here](https://www.google.com/search?q=mergesort%20space%20complexity%20site%3Astackoverflow.com) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=mergesort%20vs%20quicksort%20site%3Astackoverflow.com)).

Answer (score 3):

I not python expert, but you should write

```
left_half = arr[:mid]
right_half = arr[mid:]

left_half = mergeSort(left_half)
right_half = mergeSort(right_half)
```

Because your mergeSort return copy of sorted array.